# Can the "goat cabbage wolf" problem be solved using integer programming?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-programming

Question:

Can you solve the "[goat cabbage wolf](http://www.mathcats.com/explore/river/crossing.html)" problem using integer programming.

If so could I get an outline of the solution or a reference to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll bite.

I could implement this using the concept of 'inventory'. After each trip we have:
$$
  inv_{trip,side,item} = inv_{trip-1,side,item} + delivered_{trip,side,item} - takenaway_{trip,side,item} 
$$
We also have initial inventory and required final inventory. The equations look like:

[image]

The equations to forbid certain configurations are similar to what I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244061/get-multiple-solutions-for-0-1-knapsack-milp-with-lpsolveapi/34245156#34245156).

The main decisions looks like:

```
----     64 VARIABLE pax.L  items taken on each trip

                 wolf        goat     cabbage

trip1.L2R                       1
trip2.L2R           1
trip2.R2L                       1
trip3.L2R                                   1
trip4.L2R                       1
```